# Can I build a parameterless constructor for a parametric type in an outer constructor?

Tags: julia

In order to instantiate a type like `x = MyType{Int}()`

I can define a inner constructor.

```
immutable MyType{T}
    x::Vector{T}

    MyType() = new(T[])
end
```

Is it possible to achieve the same objective using an outer constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the following syntax:

```
(::Type{MyType{T}}){T}() = MyType{T}(T[])
```

The thing in the first set of parentheses describes the called object. `::T` means "of type T", so this is a definition for calling an object of type `Type{MyType{T}}`, which means the object `MyType{T}` itself. Next `{T}` means that `T` is a parameter of this definition, and a value for it must be available in order to call this definition. So `MyType{Int}` matches, but `MyType` doesn't. From there on, the syntax should be familiar.

This syntax is definitely a bit fiddly and unintuitive, and we hope to improve it in a future version of the language, hopefully v0.6.

Comment: I should add that this syntax is only available as of v0.5.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but if you cannot build parameterless function like this:

```
julia> f{T}() = show(T)
WARNING: static parameter T does not occur in signature for f at none:1.
The method will not be callable.
f (generic function with 1 method)
```

therefore you won't be able to do this:

```
julia> immutable MyType{T}
           x::Vector{T} 
       end

julia> MyType{T}() = MyType{T}(T[])
WARNING: static parameter T does not occur in signature for call at none:1.
The method will not be callable.
MyType{T}

julia> x = MyType{Int}()
ERROR: MethodError: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{MyType{Int64}})
...
```

Every outer constructor is also a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can say

```
f(T::Type) = show(T)
```

and also

```
MyType(T::Type) = MyType(T[])
```

But julia needs to see the type in the call to know which you want.

Comment: Yes but it's not considered as outer constructor for MyType{T}